# Determine if python function is a generator

Tags: python, reflection, generator

In Python, I have a function that has a function as a parameter.  The function is expected to return a string.  However, in some cases, the function is a generator.  Is there a way to determine if a function is a generator or not?

Comment: `inspect.isgeneratorfunction`. But it's not necessarily what you really want, because although it returns `True` for `def foo(): yield None`, it returns `False` for `def bar(): return (x for x in [None])`, which is functionally identical. So what do you really want to know: whether the function is a generator function; whether the function returns a generator object; whether the result of the function can be iterated over multiple times; something else?

Comment: except I think sometimes the function returns a generator (I dont think the function is changing types mid-program) ... I get a syntax error if I try and put a yield and a return in the same method

Comment: If the function "is expected to return a string", then you must treat it as if it returns a string. Don't bother checking the types, just let the TypeError happen.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Python functions can *either* use `return` with a value, *or* use `yield` (plus, optionally, both kinds of function can contain a `return` statement with no value -- in the first type this means `return None`, in the second type it means end of generation). Not both. So if you're putting a `yield` in a function that's supposed to return a string, that's an error.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: It's perfectly legal to have a `yield` and a `return` in the same function (as long as the `return` has no value). But having a `yield` means it's always a generator function; it doesn't change back and forth depending on whether it yields on a given code path.

Comment: Anyway, what exactly are you trying to do here? What do you want to happen if the function is a generator function/returns a generator/returns an iterator/returns a non-string/whatever? Knowing what you're trying to do is the only way to figure out how to do it…

Comment: @JoranBeasley: anyway, since the question is about a function that takes another function as a parameter, my interpretation of the question was that the caller sometimes passes in a "regular" function (with `return some_string`) and sometimes passes in a generator function (with `yield`). But that remains to be seen when the questioner gets back here :-)

Comment: Starting in Python 3.3, generators can contain both `yield` and non-trivial `return` ([PEP 380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380)).

Comment: ahh thats what I get for using 2.6

Comment: Clarification: I need the full string value out of the input function.  Sometimes the input function is a function that returns a string, other times the input function is a generator that can build a string when iterated over.

inspect.isgeneratorfunction is the answer I was looking for; though, the ''.join(func()) is a nice option too.  Thanks Steve and abarnert.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you have a function that sometimes returns a string, and sometimes a generator (or maybe even another kind of iterator) over single-character strings. (Or, maybe, sometimes you have a function that always returns a string, and sometimes a generator function that yields characters. But that doesn't make much difference.)

If that's true, there's probably no reason to check in the first place. You can get a string, loop over the characters, etc. without having to know which one you got:

```
s = ''.join(my_function())

for ch in my_function():
    do_something_with_char(ch)
```

(If I've guessed wrong, this answer may be completely irrelevant to your question.)

Answer (score 0):

how bout

```
if not isinstance(result,basestring):
    #its not a string type object so it must be a generator
```

or

```
import types
if isinstance(result,types.GeneratorType):
```